# Use svg with angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I am learning angularjs and I am trying use `ng-repeat` to create an svg graph.

I have this html:

```svg
<svg>
    <g id="g_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="i in range" ng-cloak>
        <rect x="{{i / 5}}" y="{{i / 5}}" width="{{i / 5}}" height="{{i / 5}}"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

the 'range' is just a simple array which is defined in controller like this:

```js
$scope.range = [100, 200, 300];
```

the html is working; the rects are rendered on my page.

However, Chrome keeps throwing the following error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="{{i / 5}}"    js/angular.js:1584
  JQLiteClone   js/angular.js:1584
  JQLite.(anonymous function)   js/angular.js:2163
  publicLinkFn  js/angular.js:3862
  ngRepeatWatch js/angular.js:13641
  Scope.$digest js/angular.js:7889
  Scope.$apply  js/angular.js:8097
    js/angular.js:961
  invoke    js/angular.js:2857
  resumeBootstrapInternal   js/angular.js:959
  bootstrap js/angular.js:973
  angularInit   js/angular.js:934
    js/angular.js:14756
  fire  js/jquery-2.0.0.js:2863
  self.fireWith js/jquery-2.0.0.js:2975
  jQuery.extend.ready   js/jquery-2.0.0.js:398
  completed js/jquery-2.0.0.js:93
```

It seems that it does not quite like what I am doing...

Does anyone have an idea why I'm receiving this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is Chrome sees the Angular interpolation str as an invalid value for those attributes (since at least at one time the element actually exists in the DOM -- though invisibly -- with "invalid" values). I have written a solution that is in line with other Angular solutions as to browser handling of special attributes where instead of using x, y, width, and height, you specify ng-x, ng-y, ng-width, and ng-height and the real attributes are set after the values are interpolated.

Here is the solution [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evictor/WHfPp/). I'm going to submit a patch to Angular to see if we can get this in the core.

HTML

```svg
<div ng-app="SampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <svg>
        <g id="g_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="i in range" ng-cloak>
            <rect ng-x="{{i / 5}}" ng-y="{{i / 5}}" ng-width="{{i / 5}}" ng-height="{{i / 5}}"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

JS

```js
angular.module('SampleApp', [], function() {})
    .directive('ngX', function() {
        return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('ngX', function(x) {
                elem.attr('x', x);
            });
        };
    })
    .directive('ngY', function() {
        return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('ngY', function(y) {
                elem.attr('y', y);
            });
        };
    })
    .directive('ngWidth', function() {
        return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('ngWidth', function(width) {
                elem.attr('width', width);
            });
        };
    })
    .directive('ngHeight', function() {
        return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('ngHeight', function(height) {
                elem.attr('height', height);
            });
        };
    });

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.range = [100, 200, 300];
}
```

Comment: angular 1.1.4 (or maybe earlier) has a new generic directive to bind late https://github.com/lrlopez/angular.js/commit/638e6fdbd60f606dfbe21303f9c94e6d57f0764a

Comment: @markus, both of your solutions worked brilliantly, I adopt the attr-ng- approach as it has in the code base

Comment: As this is the accepted answer, I think it's worth changing it to use the official late binding attributes `ng-attr-x`, `ng-attr-y`... and keep the rest as a DIY

Answer (score 12):

Markus' comment to use late binding is best.

Ie. prefix your attribute with either 'ng-attr-', 'ng:attr:' or 'ng_attr_', like this:

```
<rect ng:attr:x="{{i / 5}}" ng:attr:y="{{i / 5}}" ng:attr:width="{{i / 5}}" nng:attr:height="{{i / 5}}"></rect>
```

Comment: Perfect, I had the same issues when using ng-repeat  it was showing errors when using x, and y svg attrs and this solved it.