# Angular directive report error about SVG attribute while render it correctly

Tags: angularjs, svg

All:

When I tried to render a simple bubble chart with Angular, it keeps giving me error like:

> jquery.min.js:3 Error:  attribute cx: Expected length,
>   "{{d.cx}}".

But the render result is correct, I wonder how this happens and how to avoid those error?

My Code is like:

```js
 var app = angular.module("vp", []);
 app
   .controller("main", function($scope) {
     $scope.data = [{
       cx: 200,
       cy: 200
     }, {
       cx: 100,
       cy: 100
     }]
   })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="vp">

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="main">

  <svg width="300" height="300">
    <g>
      <circle ng-repeat="d in data track by $index" cx="{{d.cx}}" cy="{{d.cy}}" fill="red" r="25"></circle>
    </g>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the SVG gets rendered before Angular has bound the model values, and values of the form "{{d.cx}} are obviously not valid values.

The simplest solution is just to use `ng-attr-xxx` format for your SVG attributes.

```
ng-attr-cx="{{d.cx}}" ng-attr-cy="{{d.cy}}"
```

Then the real attributes won't get proper values till angular has executed its first digest.

You don't need to use a directive.

Answer (score 1):

This is a svg angular weirdness other people have had the problem and come up with a solution.  See [Use svg with angularjs ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318768/use-svg-with-angularjs-ng-repeat)