# angularjs calculation errors when building an svg graph

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

Other Solution: [Use svg with angularjs ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318768/use-svg-with-angularjs-ng-repeat)

Im building a graph using angularjs, everything is working as it should be but i get a ton of error messages which I can't really resolve. I have an array with data points and attributes. In the html code i call upon needed attributes like below:

```
 <circle ng-repeat="point in points | limitTo : points.length-1" 
    cx="{{500 / maxX * point.xValue}}" cy="{{points[$index].insulin / maxY * 400}}"
    r="3" fill="red"/>
```

All messages are somewhat like this, They all concern expressions within brackets:
Error:  attribute y2: Expected length, "{{points[$index …".

Is this not the way to do it? Should I do the calculations in a different way? I wouldn't know how else to calculate points.

codepen link:
https://codepen.io/mbezema/pen/bvWPVm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is only a warning, not an error, and it is only visible in the developer console, so from a user perspective, nothing serious happens; the graph gets rendered correctly.

What you encounter is a restriction of AngularJS that has been addressed in newer Angular versions: before tha data binding happens, the browser shortly reads the AngularJS command string, i. e.

```
cx="{{500 / maxX * point.xValue}}"
```

and complains that this string is not a number. Since immediately afterwards AngularJS exchanges it with

```
cx="15"
```

the browser is satisfied, and renders the circle correctly.

If you really want to avoid these messages, a possible solution would be to leave out the attributes from the SVG namespace that have a data binding and only write them from Javascript. You could define two simple directives:

```
app.directive('graphPoint', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.attr('cx', 500 / scope.maxX * scope.point.xValue)
      element.attr('cy', scope.point.insulin / scope.maxY * 400)
    },
    scope: true
  }
});

app.directive('graphLine', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.attr('x1', 500 / scope.maxX * scope.point.xValue)
      element.attr('y1', scope.point.insulin / scope.maxY * 400)
      element.attr('x2', 500 / scope.maxX * scope.points[scope.$index + 1].xValue)
      element.attr('y2', scope.points[scope.$index + 1].insulin / scope.maxY * 400)
    },
    scope: true
  }
});
```

and write your `<svg>` as

```
<svg height="400" width="500">
  <line graph-line ng-repeat="point in points | limitTo : points.length-1" />
  <circle graph-point ng-repeat="point in points" r="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Note: I've assumed you inadvertantly left out the last data point and removed the filter from the circle `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! Helps with making the html more concise as well.
The filter was because the last line connects the last point with the first.

Comment: In my own implementation i use a custom directive to check for window resizes and then adjust the graph accordingly. By using your directives i can't get it to respond to the window resizes. Any tips on how to adjust to that? 

https://codepen.io/mbezema/pen/bvWPVm